# The Fourier Coefficients of $\cos(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

To begin I simply went with the definition:
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k\cdot e^{ikw_ot} \implies f_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} f(t)\cdot e^{-ikw_ot} \,dt$$
And before plugging $\cos(x)$ I first expressed it in therm of complex exponentials:
$$f_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} cos(t)\cdot e^{-ikw_ot} \,dt=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\cdot e^{-ikw_ot} \,dt 
= \frac{1}{2T}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{T} e^{it}\cdot e^{-ikw_ot} \,dt+\int_{0}^{T} e^{-it}\cdot e^{-ikw_ot} \,dt\Bigg)$$
After going through both of the integrals I end up witht the following result:
$$f_k = \frac{-i}{4\pi}\cdot\Bigg[\frac{1}{1-kw_o}(e^{i(1-kw_o)T}-1)+\frac{1}{1+kw_o}(e^{i(1+kw_o)T}-1)   \Bigg]$$
However I could only find very little to verify this expression and the length of the result makes me wonder if I am missing any simplification.

Comment: This is correct, but you didn't consider $\omega$ that matches the period $T$.

Comment: Do you mean using $T=\frac{2\pi}{w_o}$ to simplify $w_o \cdot T$ into $2\pi$?

Comment: You don't use $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$ to simplify things, you _need_ it because otherwise your formulas are simply _wrong_!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: why do you say that they are wrong ?

Comment: Because given that $f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k\cdot e^{ikw_ot}$ it's simply not true that $f_k=\frac1T\int_0^T$etc unless $T$ has the right value. I mean it's obvious that there's at most one value of $T$ making this work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should note that your very first assertion, "$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k\cdot e^{ikw_ot} \implies f_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} f(t)\cdot e^{-ikw_ot} \,dt$" is simply wrong, **unless** you begin by specifying the value of $T$. (From what you write one gets the impression that that formula is valid for *every* $T$; that's obviously impossible, right?)

In any case there's no need to do any calculation. You have $$\frac12e^{it}+\frac12e^{-it}=\cos(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k\cdot e^{ikw_ot};$$ now since $\cos$ has period $2\pi$ we must have $\omega_0=1$, and then the uniqueness of the coefficients for Fourier series shows that $$f_k=\begin{cases}\frac12,&(k=\pm1),
\\0,&(k\ne\pm1).\end{cases}$$(You already know two Fourier series for $\cos(t)$, and they must be the same.)